# How to debug a mistake when inserting data into the table?

Tags: php

PHP code didn't insert.

```
<?php
$message = " ";
require "database.php";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $message = "Email or Password is Incorrect";
    } else {
        $email = '$_POST[email]';
        $pass = '$_POST[password]';
        if ($email && $pass) {
            $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "auth");
            $sqli = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES($email, $pass)";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqli)) {
                $message = "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                $message = "Cannot create user!";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

$conn = mysqli_conncect("localhost","root","","auth");
```

I tried everything but not found the mistake to insert the query into the table.

Comment: Please do not post code as a screenshot.  Copy and paste it instead.

Comment: Have you ever heard of SQL injection?

Comment: I've voted to close because of the image. _Please_ fix it, and ping me after you've done so, and I will see if it can be reopened. (Of course if the solution is merely the problem in the answer below, then the question may be closed as typo/not reproducible).

Comment: You have a spelling error in the code you've supplied - `mysqli_conncect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotation in your else statement. PHP will interpret it as a string instead of a POST variable.

That is:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```